# no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh

Today when I tried to copy files using ssh in macOS 13.4 to Ubuntu 22.04LTS like this:

```
ssh -vvv -p 22 root@41.16.74.29 'mkdir -p .ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

shows error:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@47.116.74.159: Permission denied (publickey).
```

it seems the ssh look for the `id_dsa` by default. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? this command works fine in the past long time.

Comment: It is not clear what key you are expecting to use to connect as root to the remote system.  To put a public key in place on the remote system, you obviously can't use *that* key to connect with. Please update your question with what your expectations and intentions were.

Comment: If you are expecting to connect with an RSA key, ensure that the server is still accepting this older type of key. If you are expecting to authenticate with a password, then ensure that the server is accepting passwords. This is not an answer as we don't know how you're intending to authenticate.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.ssh/
```

If the key file is not present, generate a new SSH key pair

Comment: I have already tried to regenerated the key, but did not work.

Comment: Generating a new key pair won't do anything if the account on the remote server does not have the public key.